# HELP! Frameset Tag with Dojo use Memory Leak in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, dojo, frameset

I develop the Web application with "dojo 1.3.1" now.

The application uses frameset tag for a layout. the fram parts in "menu
domain" and "the contents domain".

When I chose a menu,"the contents domain" displays pages.
"memory leak" happened, when I update screen by pushing the update
button (F5Key) or when I choosing a page from menu.

I conducted an investigation into a problem by many methods, but was not
able to solve it.

I want to solve this problem. Do not you know a good method?

The browser that I use is "Internet Explorer 7".

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have asked this question on the dojo-interest mailing list too. You can see the response here:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user/40060